# How to set inline style at RadEditor control's body element

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, radeditor

I want to set inline style at body element of Telerik's Radeditor BUT i want to do this without the radeditor css file which is the official solution.

For example i want the body of the editor to have inline font-family when editor initialized.

It should be inline style for my purposes.I use radeditor as email editor ,so the body will get through sanitization providers.

Any solution either form client-side or from Code-behind C# will help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to get reference to the content area on the client:

```
<telerik:RadEditor
   ID="RadEditor1"
   OnClientLoad="OnClientLoad"
   runat="server">
</telerik:RadEditor>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnClientLoad(editor, args) {
        var style = editor.get_contentArea().style;
        style.backgroundImage = "none";
        style.backgroundColor = "black";
        style.color = "red";
        style.fontFamily = "Arial";
        style.fontSize = 15 + "px";
    }
</script>
```